# Why can't I compare a procedural variable to nil?

Tags: delphi, pointers

Anders Melander's Drag Drop suite has the following code snippet in the unit `DragDrop.pas`:

```
var
  URLMONDLL: THandle = 0;
  _CopyStgMedium: function(const cstgmedSrc: TStgMedium; var stgmedDest: TStgMedium): HResult; stdcall = nil;

function CopyStgMedium(const SrcMedium: TStgMedium; var DstMedium: TStgMedium): boolean;
begin
  // ....
  if (URLMONDLL = 0) then
  begin
    URLMONDLL := LoadLibrary('URLMON.DLL');
    if (URLMONDLL <> 0) then
      @_CopyStgMedium := GetProcAddress(URLMONDLL, 'CopyStgMedium');
  end;

  if (@_CopyStgMedium = nil) then  <<-- E2008 Incompatible types
    raise Exception.Create(sNoCopyStgMedium);

  Result := (Succeeded(_CopyStgMedium(SrcMedium, DstMedium)));
end;
```

All these variants compile:

```
if (@@_CopyStgMedium = nil) then  <<-- logical error, is a pointer to the procedural var
if (pointer(@_CopyStgMedium) = nil) then <<-- correct
if not(Assigned(@_CopyStgMedium)) then   <<-- correct
```

Why am I getting `E2008 Incompatible types` here?
Note that I have typed @ operator set to true. `{$T+}`
But that still does not explain why I can't compare against `nil`, isn't nil compatible with any pointer?.

Comment: It's not me, it's Anders's code. He's using `@` all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the use of the `@` operator is wrong and needless here. It just adds confusion, in my opinion.

Write the code like this:

```
function CopyStgMedium(const SrcMedium: TStgMedium; var DstMedium: TStgMedium): boolean;
begin
  // ....
  if (URLMONDLL = 0) then
  begin
    URLMONDLL := LoadLibrary('URLMON.DLL');
    if (URLMONDLL <> 0) then
      _CopyStgMedium := GetProcAddress(URLMONDLL, 'CopyStgMedium');
  end;

  if not Assigned(_CopyStgMedium) then
    raise Exception.Create(sNoCopyStgMedium);

  Result := (Succeeded(_CopyStgMedium(SrcMedium, DstMedium)));
end;
```

As for what the `@` operator does here, it disambiguates between calling the function, and referring to it. So,

```
if _CopyStgMedium = nil then
```

is invalid because that is an attempt to call the function. On the face of it

```
if @_CopyStgMedium = nil then
```

should work, but because you have typed address, then `@_CopyStgMedium` is a typed function pointer and not comparable with `nil` apparently. You can cast away the type like this if you wish:

```
if Pointer(@_CopyStgMedium) = nil then
```

But I think that `Assigned` is much better.

This is quite weird though. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types#Procedural_Types_in_Statements_and_Expressions) says:

> In some situations it is less clear how a procedural variable should
>   be interpreted. Consider the statement:
>
> ```
> if F = MyFunction then ...;
> ```
>
> In this case, the occurrence of F results in a function call; the
>   compiler calls the function pointed to by F, then calls the function
>   MyFunction, then compares the results. The rule is that whenever a
>   procedural variable occurs within an expression, it represents a call
>   to the referenced procedure or function. In a case where F references
>   a procedure (which doesn't return a value), or where F references a
>   function that requires parameters, the previous statement causes a
>   compilation error. To compare the procedural value of F with
>   MyFunction, use:
>
> ```
> if @F = @MyFunction then ...;
> ```
>
> @F converts F into an untyped pointer variable that contains an
>   address, and @MyFunction returns the address of MyFunction.

Clearly though, when typed addresses are enabled, `@F` is not an untyped pointer. If it was, then the cast to `Pointer` in my code above would have no effect.

So this documentation does not match the observed behaviour when typed addresses are enabled. When typed addresses are enabled, `@` does not yield an untyped pointer when applied to an expression of procedural type. Johan correctly points out that in older versions, for instance XE3, `@` does yield an untyped pointer even when typed addresses are enabled. So perhaps the documentation is correct, but the compiler is defective. I suspect that this is so. Either way, a bug report should be submitted.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, however it still does not explain why I cannot compare the untyped pointer against `nil`.

Comment: To recap: `@` is bad, because it produces an untyped pointer. Except when using procedural variables, in which case `@` produces a typed procedural pointer (which for some unknown reason is incompatible with nil).

Comment: I was relying too much on the documentation. It's wrong when typed addresses are enabled. I think that's better now. This library seems like it wants `{$T-}`. That's the expedient approach.

Comment: The library works fine with `{$T+}` it's just a few lines that need an explicit cast to pointer and then everything works.

Comment: The thing is, changing to `{$T+}` won't change behaviour, and you presumably aren't going to modify the code, so you might just be making work for yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan; My upvote for using `Assigned`. That is IMO the proper way to do this..IIRC, this kind of problems (to avoid function calls when comparing procedural types) was the main reason to introduce `Assigned`.

Comment: I just found out the following line in `DragDrop.Inc`: `// The following are not realy nescessary, but they are good practice.
{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}      // @ operator returns typed pointer.
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}   // Typed consts are R/O.` So if `{$T+}` was always on, why does the compile break in XE7, but not XE? When did the behavior change?

Comment: `{$T+} ... if @_CopyStgMedium = nil then` compiles in XE3 but not XE6. So your sleuthing is good. This looks more like a compiler error than a documentation error in that light. I guess I've never noticed this because of my strong aversion to `@` with procedural types.